# How to access network folders (using UNC notation) with cmd commands?

Tags: windows

How do I access my network folders in a cmd window?

When I am trying to access as `cd \\computername`, then it outputs an error message saying:

> CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pushd`  instead of `cd`. `pushd` to create a temporary virtual drive. When you're done, use popd to delete it and it goes back to your previous directory automatically. Something like:

```
C:\a\local\path> pushd \\somewhere
```

And after you're done use popd.